# peculiar jQuery .closest when using $(this)

Tags: jquery

This statement does **not** work:

```
$(this).closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
```

But this statement does:

```
$("div").closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
```

It is being used in this context (with the mark.js library):

```
instance.markRegExp(/mypattern/gi, {className:"myclass", done: function() {
    $(this).closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
  }});
```

SOLUTION: (courtesy Baro and Chay22):

```
$(node).closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
```

context,

```
instance.markRegExp(/mypattern/gi, {className:"myclass", each: function(node) {
        $(node).closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
      }});
```

Comment: have also tried     $(this.element).closest

Comment: use `each` instead of `done` to get marked element. Those options also don't have `this` reference bound. Take an example, https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/blob/master/src/mark.js#L772 No, `.call`, `.apply`, nor `bind`

Comment: yes, when using the option 'done' the function returns a count, but with 'each' the function returns the node which is what i was looking for. importantly, $(this) still does not work and $(node) must be used to access the DOM element

Comment: Yeah, as I said earlier, no `.call`, `.apply`, `.bind` = no `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you want exactly without see the HTML, and I think something is wrong on your logic. This because you add `myclass` at all element highlighted and with `closest` you are looking for a father element with this class.

---

```
$("div").closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
```

*This work because is a simple JQuery command, nothing else.*

---

```
$(this).closest(".myclass").addClass("myextraclass");
```

*`this` in that context is the `Mark` object, and not the elements highlighted or the father element.*

---

If you want all elements highlighted try this:

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/u0km6adb/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="findhere">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
</div>

<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut augue neque. Cras euismod varius metus ut bibendum. 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.findhere { color:red; }
.myclass { text-decoration:underline; }
.myextraclass { font-weight:bold; }
.green { color:green; }
```

**JS**

```
var instance = new Mark("div.findhere");
instance.markRegExp(/ipsum/gi, {className:"myclass", each: function(node) {
    $(node).addClass("green");
    $(node).closest(".findhere").addClass("myextraclass");
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jquery syntax of mark.ks if you are using jquery..

```
$(".context").markRegExp(regexp [, options]);
```